# Partition and Boot problem Ubuntu 20.04 (GRUB 2.04)

Tags: partitioning, grub2, 20.04, boot-repair, boot-partition

My computer boots with GNU GRUB Version 2.04 right after I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (with LVM and full encryption). I arrive directly to GRUB console (Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. for the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions).

My computer had already Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed after an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (with LVM and full encryption). I had some issue with the swap file (apparently too small) and decided to go for a fresh install.

The computer is a Dell Latitude 7370 (with a SSD). The BIOS was recently updated (1.19.5). No dual boot.

I did ran Boot Repair from a live-USB but there was not the option to do a "Recommended repair". Here is the pastbin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3Nr9jWWnZW/

`grub> exit` gets me to a blue screen "boot restoration option" where I can either reset the system or continue boot. Both get me back to the grub console.

In order to get past the GRUB console, I need to enter the following command ((hd0,1) having another name for me). I found this solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot/330852#330852)

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

This get me to Ubuntu. I ran `apt-update` `grub-update` `apt-upgrade`.
But when I restart the computer. I am back to the GRUB console at boot.

Result for `sudo df -h`

```
    Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev                       3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev
    tmpfs                      786M  1,9M  784M   1% /run
    /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  232G  6,0G  214G   3% /
    tmpfs                      3,9G  466M  3,4G  12% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                      5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs                      3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/loop0                 9,2M  9,2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
    /dev/loop2                  55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
    /dev/loop3                  63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
    /dev/loop1                  98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10185
    /dev/loop4                 256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
    /dev/loop5                  30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
    /dev/loop6                  50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
    /dev/nvme0n1p5             704M  202M  451M  31% /boot
    /dev/nvme0n1p1             511M   18M  494M   4% /boot/efi
    tmpfs                      786M   52K  786M   1% /run/user/1000
    /dev/loop7                  56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
    /dev/loop8                  31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9721
    /dev/loop9                  51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/481
    /dev/loop10                218M  218M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
```

Other information from `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: THNSN5256GPUK NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa17a7df7

Device         Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/nvme0n1p2      1052670 500117503 499064834   238G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      1052672   2549759   1497088   731M 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p6      2551808 500117503 497565696 237,3G 83 Linux
```

I've spend some time trying to find a solution without any success. Any idea what would be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Do not know LVM nor encryption. But you have mixed UEFI & BIOS and MBR(msdos) with gpt. With UEFI, you should use gpt partitioning. And only if you have an old system that has to have Windows in BIOS boot mode should you use the old MBR partitioning. You then have grub in MBR for BIOS boot and grub in an ESP for UEFI boot on MBR drive which Ubuntu allows but really should not. But you have to be consistent always UEFI or always BIOS. And then if UEFI really only use gpt.

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your reply. I've updated my question as in the meantime I managed to get past GRUB to Ubuntu. But after rebooting the computer, I'm back to GRUB console. I am not confident enough to run `boot-repair`, as I am afraid to mess things up even more. Do you know how can I fix clean my partitioning ?

Comment: If I follow these instructions in full, I should be ok? [Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019)

Comment: Never used LVM nor encryption, but instructions look ok. You may want to reveiw these also. Instructions for dual boot make it more complicated, but looks similar otherwise. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption/
Full-system encryption with manual control and dual-booting Paddy Landau
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357627 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399092
GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 But change to gpt will erase drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by @oldfred, partitionning was messed up and probably the cause of the problem. I did a new fresh install following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019) and it all works well now.